# Unable to change signpost icon of Clarity Design System

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, vmware-clarity

I am unable to change the icon of the **signpost** element i.e. `clr-signpost` of *[Clarity Design System](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/signposts)* (Version: 0.9.0), both in Chrome & IE. The signpost is showing the default info (i) icon. No error is displayed in console.

In my Angular 4 project I am using the signpost element inside a column of a datatable of *[PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/)* (Version: 4.1.1).

Does anyone have any ideas in this issue?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- PrimeNG Datatable -->
<p-datatable>
   ....
   ....
   <p-column field="story" [style]="{'overflow':'visible', 'text-align':'center'}" header="Story" styleClass="col-button">
       <ng-template let-item="rowData" pTemplate="body">
           <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-align:center;">                                
                <clr-signpost>
                    <clr-icon clrSignpostTrigger shape="avatar"></clr-icon>
                    <clr-signpost-content *clrIfOpen>
                       <p><code class="clr-code">{{item.story}}</code></p>
                    </clr-signpost-content>
                </clr-signpost>
           </div>                                                    
      </ng-template>
   </p-column>               
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We added custom signpost triggers in an [alpha release of v10](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.10.0-alpha.3). It looks like you are using v9 and Signposts only have a default trigger. If you upgrade to v10 or later you will enable the custom trigger declaration on your component.

Comment: Yes! This was the reason...I have upgraded the version to v.10, and now it is running with whatever icon / button link I wanted. Great help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the class attribute to the to the clr-icon and give it the icon class you want.
Also I found this code at the Clarity that describies how to use custom triggers

```
<div class="signpost-item">
        <h6>Clarity Icon</h6>
        <clr-signpost>
            <clr-icon shape="avatar" 
                      class="is-solid has-badge-info" 
                      clrSignpostTrigger>
            </clr-icon>
            <clr-signpost-content [clrPosition]="'bottom-middle'" *clrIfOpen>
                Lorem ipsum...
            </clr-signpost-content>
        </clr-signpost>
</div>
```

you will find more examples under the Custom Triggers
 section

Comment: if the problem remains the same try adding this code to your angular component encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None under the component decorator

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the class your are talking about will introduce some added features (like, solid & badge info) to the icon... though I have tried all of these, nothing was working. Its seems the 'clrSignpostTrigger' is not working some how as i think.